# Using a "slow" hash function with fewer iterations vs. a "fast" one with more?

Tags: hash, cryptographic-hash-function

Any benefit to using a slower hash function with fewer iterations vs. a fast one with more?  Assuming you are attempting to protect a password..

Answer (score 0):

You want something that's a *better* hash. And that's not necessarily received by more iterations -- the algorithm itself has to be better.

Comment: What about SHA2 vs. future SHA3, where SHA3 would be considered faster AND better?  If you are trying to slow down a brute force attack, would slower with less iterations be advantageous?

Comment: @Ross: I'm not familiar with their details, so no idea, sorry. :\

Answer (score 0):

when protecting password simply use good hash function (for example SHA2). Good reference is [NIST Recommendation for Applications Using Approved Hash Algorithms](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-107/NIST-SP-800-107.pdf). 
when its about "proof of work" you may consider multiple hashing